# Correct event to get order information after successful order

Tags: magento2, event-observer

My requirement is to change order status when an order is placed successfully  in Magento 2  .what is the event can I use so that I can change order status ,I have tried sales_order_save_after event but it will triggers whenever an order is saved ,I can't use this event and my orders are placed through cron also I mean if I use checkout_submit_all_after event it will only triggers only from frontend .can I know what is the best event to do this job.please suggest me  .

Answer (score 1):

Try the event

> checkout_submit_all_after

It runs after order is submitted successfully (both frontend and backend)

For example, in **events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="{vendor}_{module}_checkout_submit_all_after" instance="{Vendor}\{Module}\Observer\CheckoutSubmitAllAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And in the **Observer**

```
namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CheckoutSubmitAllAfter implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();

        // Enter your code here

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You For your answer , but this event triggers only when the order is placed using checkout in frontend, but for me orders are placed through crons also.We have subscription products , for first time when customer places an order for subscription products it will placed through frontend but for second time it will placed through crons , so checkout event won't work.

Comment: `checkout_submit_all_after` is not firing mean you don't create order right way at cron job